# State machine based spring boot application always exits instead of waiting for events

Tags: spring-boot, spring-statemachine

I want to use the spring state machine as the main processor of my application. I want to start the application, do the bootstrapping as an action of the initial state and tear down as an action of the end state. In the middle the application should wait for events.

So, I started by doing as shown in 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/html/developing-your-first-spring-statemachine-application.html
Everything works as described except that after exiting the `run` method the entire application stops and does not listen to further events.

How can this behavior be achieved? Is there a blueprint/template available? I didn't found one. Similar to a web component, listening for request, I want the state machine to wait for configured events. My application runs on a Raspberry Pi and those events are triggered by external actions like "button pressed", "a connected device delivers a measurement result".

Next to my main question I asked myself, whether spring state mechanine will work correct in my environment: I use Pi4J for hardware interaction. This framework usually uses its own threads for watching for hardware events. How will concurrent events be treated. Are actions always run synchroniously in the thread triggering the event or is there a separate thread pool?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Please, don't ask 2 questions at once. Split it into 2 separate ones.

Comment: I hope that the answer for the first question will point to some documention which also answers the second question. As I mentioned this situation is similar to the web module and if I asked for that then the solution would answer both questions. For me these are only two aspects of one missing thing and the second question should precise that what I asked for in the first question must include something answering the second question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal spring boot question as app will exit if nothing is keeping it alive. With boot apps you usually have a web layer and a thread from there keeps app alive.

statemachine docs have more info on how to configure executor to be threaded. On default execution happens in a same thread.

Pi4J is a good question as I'm not that familiar with its threading. I know that many bugs has been fixed as it used to create a lot of threads user didn't have no control and it's probably still a case. There's been some development on Pi4J to allow user to define thread factories which in theory could also passed to Spring `TaskExecutor` used by statemachine.